# "recipientType" & "relatedToType" in VF Email template

Tags: visualforce, email-template

I wanted to create an email template that can be used as custom javascript button on custom object.

So i have 2 custom object : Obj1__c  & Obj2__c. Neither of these objects are directly related to any standard object. Obj1(master) has m/d relationship with Obj2. Now i have create a custom javascript button on Obj1 to send email.

.toAddresses is set to "{!Obj1__c.Email__c}";

Now I wanted to crate an vf email template to show all realted records (Obj2)data in email template. But not sure about the what values should i select for "recipientType" & "relatedToType"

All the online vf templates examples have standard object as Recipient Type hence confused.

Thanks for your time!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since based on **Obj1**, you want to display **Obj2** data in the template, so approach is:

First, the **recipientType** also called the **WhoID** and secondly the **relatedToType** also refered to as the **whatID** in regular email templates.
In addition, a **replyTo** address can be defined, so that anyone replying to the email can reply back to this address.

```
<messaging:emailTemplate recipientType="Contact"
    relatedToType="Obj1__c"
    subject="Display records related to: {!relatedTo.name}"
    replyTo="support@acme.com">
```

If you want to access **Obj2** fields, use this to verify the correct relationship name from workbench (if you have any confusion)

```
<apex:repeat var="cx" value="{!relatedTo.Obj2__r}">
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for always replying to my questions!.....but neither Obj1 nor Obj2 is realted to Contact. So i am not getting logic  of recipientType="Contact" . Also how can i access Obj2__c fields in email template. like <apex:repeat var="xx" value="{!relatedTo.Obj2}">   ???

Comment: recipientType is WhoId, think about Task object, how we define WhoId and WhatId